# Add text in the middle of line xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

Hi I have created an UML diagram in C# with nodes and edges. The nodes are connected to the other nodes with edges, but I want to add text to the edges.

To draw the edges I have use Bindings to startNode and endNode (simple).

```
<Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding StartNode.Center_x}" Y1="{Binding StartNode.Center_y}" X2="{Binding EndNode.Center_x}" Y2="{Binding EndNode.Center_y}" StrokeThickness="5"/>
```

It is simple to add text before or after the edge, but if I do so, it is overidden by the connected node.

My question is, how do I add a label or textbox in the middle of the line?

Do I need to create two lines, one at the beginning and before the text, and the second after the text and to the end? And if so, how to?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to approach your problem is to have a single UI Container like a Panel, and then inside the container you draw the line and put the text as you wish, that may help you to overlay the multiple objects dilemma.